# How can I subtract the value of a label with an integer

Tags: c#

I have a label set to a value of a number.  what I am trying to do is on the click of a button subtract a number from the value of the label.  when I try this I get the error below.

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type string.

```
        DateTime start = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
        DateTime end = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;

        TimeSpan difference = end - start;

        int days = difference.Days;
        int rdays = Convert.ToInt32(Holidays_Number_lbl.Text);
        Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = days.ToString() - rdays.ToString();
```

Also If I replace the `-` with a `+` it works but if the label value is `20` and add 1 get the result `120` instead of `21`? not sure why.

Comment: `Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = (days - rdays).ToString()`;

Comment: Firstly INT isn't a type its `int`, Secondly you cant subtract 2 strings (words) from each other,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to subtract two strings instead of two integers. Try this:

```
int days = difference.Days;
int rdays = Convert.ToInt32(Holidays_Number_lbl.Text);
Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = (days - rdays).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't subtract two variable with `string`  datatype, because `-` is not defined for string variable. for solve your exception replace below code:

```
Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = (days - rdays).ToString();
```

Also you ask:

> Also If i replace the '-' with a '+' it works but if the label value is 20 and i add 1 i get the result 120 instead of 21? not sure why.

The `+` operator is defined for strings variable and when you sum up two string variable the result is concatenation of two variable, for example in your case:

```
Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = "1" + "20"; //The result become 120
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do mathematical operations on strings. So don't convert them to strings until *after* the subtraction happens.

```
Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = (days - rdays).ToString();
```

The reason why `+` works is because that is the [concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#string-concatenation) for strings - it is not a mathematical operator in that case.